# How to SAVE checkbox & INCREASE integer for each checkmark?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, save, integer

**If a User checks off a box how can we save it?**

Right now if this happens the checkmark disappears upon refreshing and in the index `<%= habit.missed %>` it still shows `0` instead of `1` (I don't know if a true or false boolean would work for this).

**There are 15 checkboxes, for each box a User checks, how can we add +1 to `t.integer :missed`?**

In other words the checkboxes would represent 1 if clicked and 0 if not clicked.

LAYOUT LOOK EX

```
        Missed:
Level 1: [ ] [ ] [ ]
Level 2: [√] [√] [ ]
Level 3: [√] [ ] [ ]
Level 4: [√] [√] [√] [ ]
Level 5: [ ] [ ] [ ]
```

END GOAL

The +1 will then add 1 day to the `:level`, since you wouldn't count a day as completed if you didn't do it. **How can we for each box clicked add +1 to `:level`?**

With the example above the User would need 2 extra days before he could move onto level 3, one extra day before he could move onto level 4, etc.

**AND if you miss three days in a level how can we force the User back to restarting that level?** Ex, if I'm on day 66 and checked off `:missed` three times in the Level 4 row as shown above how can we recalculate the day to be 45 again?

At this point for Level 4 an additional box would need to appear after every checkmark via AJAX in case on his second go around he misses a day. We could just refresh the boxes shown in that level I don't think because we would still need for the purpose of counting how many days he has left.

```html
class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
before_save :set_level
acts_as_taggable
serialize :committed, Array

scope :missed, -> { where(missed: 1) }

def levels
  committed_wdays = committed.map { |day| Date::DAYNAMES.index(day.titleize) }
  n_days = ((date_started.to_date)..Date.today).count { |date| committed_wdays.include? date.wday }

  case n_days   
  when 0..9
    1
  when 10..24
    2
  when 25..44
    3
  when 45..69
    4
  when 70..99
    5
  else
    "Mastery"
 end
end

protected
def set_level
 self.level = levels
end 
end
end
```

```html
<%= simple_form_for(@habit) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

<div class="america">
<form>

  <div class="committed">
  <%= f.label "Committed to:" %>&nbsp;
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :committed, Date::DAYNAMES, :downcase, :to_s %>
  </div>

  <p><div class="date-group">
    <label> Started: </label>
    <%= f.date_select :date_started, :order => [:month, :day, :year], class: 'date-select' %>
  </div></p>

  <p><%= f.text_field :trigger, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Trigger' %></p>
  <p><%= f.text_field :tag_list, habit: @habit.tag_list.to_s.titleize, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Action' %></p>
  <p><%= f.text_field :target, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Target' %></p>
  <p><%= f.text_field :positive, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Reward' %></p>
  <%= f.text_field :negative, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Penalty' %>
<% 5.times do |n| %>
  <%= f.label "Level #{n+1}:" %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'missed[]', value: n+1 %>
<% end %>

<div class="america2">
  <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn") do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to habits_path, class: 'btn' do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to @habit, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn' do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
  <% end %>
</div>
  
</form>
</div>
<% end %>
```

```html
class HabitsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_habit, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @habits = Habit.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @habits = Habit.all.order("date_started DESC")
      @habits = current_user.habits
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @habit = current_user.habits.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @habit = current_user.habits.build(habit_params)
    if  @habit.save
        redirect_to @habit, notice: 'Habit was successfully created.'
    else
        @feed_items = []
        render 'pages/home'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @habit.update(habit_params)
      redirect_to @habit, notice: 'Habit was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @habit.destroy
    redirect_to habits_url
  end

  private
    def set_habit
      @habit = Habit.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @habit = current_user.habits.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to habits_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this habit" if @habit.nil?
    end

    def habit_params
      params.require(:habit).permit(:missed, :left, :level, :date_started, :trigger, :target, :positive, :negative, :tag_list, :committed => [])
    end
end
```

**Thank you =]**

P.S. Open to using select boxes, checkboxes, collection_boxes, etc so long as it gets the job done.

Comment: You want to add to a boolean column? What's the purpose of the various constants in there that are all the same?

Comment: @tadman I want :missed, which is an integer to represent 1 so that when a User clicks on its box the index will add up how many boxes were clicked, therefore representing how many days the User :missed

Comment: It's still completely unclear why you have so many constants with identical contents, and even more baffling that they all contain just the value `1` repeated three times for no apparent reason. Keep in mind that columns should not have `?` in their name. Boolean columns do not have that in the literal column name, but a convenience method with `?` at the end is created automatically.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I just left that in there to give some context but I guess it just ended up creating confusion. I just wanted to save checkboxes & represent if they are checked by increasing the integer on `:missed` in the index.

Comment: And sorry the ? was part of the sentence not the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a bunch of checkboxes, just do this:

```
<%- 5.times do |n| %->
  <%= f.label "Level #{n+1}:" %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'missed[]', value: n+1 %>
<%- end -%>
```

Then you should receive a `missed` param with a series of numbers in it, each one corresponding to if that day was checked or not. If you want to know how many days were missed:

```
[params[:missed]].flatten.length
```

This handles the case where `params[:missed]` is not defined.

Comment: Tadman I think you missed a part after just do this: ... And thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Oh, it was there, just invisible. Code formatting issue, now fixed.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the code, but it still isn't saving in the _form. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean "saving the form"? If you have a valid `<form>` tag, then it should send the request to the server. You haven't given any insight into the controller code.

Comment: I've been coding for a few months now, but still find rails tough. I included the controller now. Can you see where the problem lies?

Comment: For non-standard controls like this you'll need to convert the incoming `:missed` param into something that the model can accept. The controller's job is to intermediate between the web request interface and the various models it needs to store and retrieve data. Part of this responsibility includes mapping incoming parameters. It's really not clear from your code what you're trying to do here, what the end goal is.

Comment: Normally a model like Habit would have some kind of identifying parameter, so if you're trying to manipulate which habits are associated with which users, or which habits are flagged as missed, then you'd want to provide some context on the checkboxes. Having all as `1` makes it impossible to tell which are which.

Comment: Darn I really screwed up formatting this question. I took out the stuff was needed to provide context and left in the things that created confusion. Here is the app up-to-date: github.com/RallyWithGalli/ruletoday. I added the full blown goal of my question above. I hope it's clearer now. I know it's definitely more difficult. If you could just solve one or two aspects of the question I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I figured we could continue the conversation here since this one got out of hand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28752593/how-to-integrate-missed-days-with-level-days